# How to subplot multiple categorical columns in a dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

So I can plot all my columns individually like so:

```
df['cat1'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```

But I can't figure out how to plot all of my cateogical columns in a nice looking subplot structure so I'm not endlessly scrolling.

My thinking so far is perhaps looping through my columns and generating a plot for each?:

```
for col in df.describe(include=['O']):
  df[col].value_counts().plot.bar()
  plt.show()
```

not sure where to go from there.

I appreciate this is perhaps a basic question but I've been googling for far too long and can't wrap my head around subplots. So I'd be grateful for any help you can offer! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can create an array of subplots and pass along the plot command:

```
# assuming you have 12 columns:
fig,axes = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=4, figsize=(12,8))

# use `select_dtypes` to filter instead of `describe`
for col, ax in zip(df.select_dtypes(include='O'), axes.ravel()):
    df[col].value_counts().plot.bar(ax=ax)

plt.show()
```